# Wanna be an Alchemist

Tags: code-golf, binary, bitwise

### Wanna be an Alchemist

I've been watching Full Metal Alchemist these past days and I've been wondering, It is really possible to trans-mutate matter? In the real world, I don't know if it is possible, but in the machine world, we think we "can".

---

**Problem**

Your task is, Given an input of N chemical elements (K, Mg, C, O, etc...), you are going to:

1. Get the first letter of the element
2. Convert that letter into binary
3. [Rotate 2 bits to the right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Rotate_no_carry)
4. [Apply Binary Addition](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-2/binary-addition/)
5. If the result is more that 8 bits then get the [one's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) of the result and removes the highest bit
6. Output the ASCII (ISO 8859-1) representation of the result

---

**Example**

Given Chemical Elements: `(K, Ca, Mg)`

1. Get the first letter of the element

`K, C, M`

2. Convert that letter into binary

`K => 01001011, C => 01000011, M => 01001101`

3. Rotate 2 bits to the right

`K => 11010010, C => 11010000, M => 01010011`

4. Sum bits

   `K => 11010010` +
    `C => 11010000` +
    `M => 01010011` = `111110101`
5. If the result is more that 8 bits then get the one's complement and removes the highest bit

`00001010`

6. Output the ASCII representation of the result. 
   `Result:`

---

**Test Cases**

```
(H, Mn, C) =>  Ê

(I, H, Se) =>  Ç

(K, Ca, Mg) =>
```

---

This is code golf so the shortest answer wins

Comment: When you say "Convert that letter into binary" am I correct in thinking you mean using ASCII? Or is it ok to use EBDIC or UTF-32? :)

Comment: @AndrewPiliser ASCII. Sorry if i was misunderstood

Comment: This is a great idea! In the future though, if you have an idea but it isn't a complete challenge, or if you just need help, you can use the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/48922).

Comment: The binary sum question needs addressing, the test cases don't work and the given link is about adding numbers that are represented in binary (which does not work out with the examples either). I am voting to close this as unclear in the interim (i.e. will vote to reopen when that is addressed).

Comment: @totallyhuman yuup, I really don't know why I thought I read that.

Comment: Step 3 of the problem and example don't match (shift discards bits, rotate keeps them). Also, your test cases are wrong because the problem requires "ASCII" and the result characters are not in the seven-bit character set known as ASCII (perhaps you want ISO 8859-1?)

Comment: I'd recommend changing "ASCII" to "Unicode" and remove the requirement to check whether the result is printable or not (allow the output to be the character, no matter what it is)

Comment: @Fox Sorry, I meant the Extended ASCII (ISO 8859) that includes 8 bits . About the shit, I meant rotate. I'll update my question

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing from `00000000` to `00011111` are non printable characters.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz 1) That doesn't include all the non-printable characters and 2) it adds unnecessary overhead to the challenge, which isn't recommended

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing ok, so just removing that part will be ok?

Comment: Personally, I'd allow results with more than 8 bits to stay as they were (but that's up to you). If you remove the printable part, I'd definitely vote to reopen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 44 bytes

```perl
$n+=257*ord>>2&255}{$_=chr($n>>8?~$n%256:$n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lT9vWyNRcK78oxc7OSM3I1LS2WiXeNjmjSEMlz87Owr5OJU/VyNTMSiVP8/9/Ty4PruDUf/kFJZn5ecX/dQsA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 78 bytes

```python
e=sum(ord(e[0])/4+ord(e[0])%4*64for e in input());print chr([e,~e][e>255]%256)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/rvbKukpPQ/1ba4NFcjvyhFIzXaIFZT30QbzlY10TIzScsvUkhVyMwDooLSEg1NTeuCosy8EoXkjCKN6FSdutTY6FQ7I1PTWFUjUzPN/0AjrVMrUpOVyjMyc1IVnK1AHAVnpf9KHko6Ckq@eSDSWYlLyRPEAIsFpwK53mDxRLCadCUA)

-8 bytes thanks to Jonathan Frech

Comment: [An imperative function is shorter.](https://tio.run/##PYyxDoJAEER7vmJzCckukmAQKDDa2GiMlSWhuMgeUHhcVihs/HWEK2gmeW8m475jN9jDPDdswGAkVPLpM71xkAa52teUJNlugzCLiswMAgy9BaGj8DiJhVcnWHH847ric5rndZjmBflTh5pKJ70dUcewPmmiIHBoUF1VDOph17yoxXp5W9E3T97k3W@037eLnf8)

Comment: Python 2, [78 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/rvbKukpPQ/1ba4NFcjvyhFIzXaIFZT30QbzlY10TIzScsvUkhVyMwDooLSEg1NTeuCosy8EoXkjCKN6FSdutTY6FQ7I1PTWFUjUzPN/0AjrVMrUpOVyjMyc1IVnK1AHAVnpf9KHko6Ckq@eSDSWYlLyRPEAIsFpwK53mDxRLCadCUA).

Comment: @JonathanFrech oh thanks :D